# Ruby version error with foreman run

Tags: ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, rvm, foreman

I get a Ruby version error when running `foreman run` **INSIDE** of a `foreman run`.

Here is the problem reproduced in its simplest form:

```
$ cd rails-project
$ foreman run rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.2)
2.1.0 :001 > system('foreman run pwd')
Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.0
```

I can avoid getting the error by just running `system('pwd')`.

Any insight into what's happening here?

### Environment:

```
* Mac OS X Mavericks
* RVM 1.25.28
* Ruby 2.1.0
* Foreman 0.60.0
* Rails 4.0.2
```